# Re-signing an APK and getting data through ContentProvider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, jar-signing

I am currently writing an app (App A) that depends on another app's data (App B).

Being an Android noobie, I thought that the only way to enable that is to use a `ContentProvider` and doing a query.

As it stands, the current way of doing is problematic, because App B has another signature than the one we're using for App A. This means:

- The only way we can get our apps to talk to each other is to send our apk on a signing server so that it is also signed with the same key used for App B

  - This process is not automated, so it is therefore time-inefficient (takes around 2 - 4 mins).
  - This also mean we can't set debug points, which causes us a lot of pain when trying to see what data exactly is being returned by the `ContentProvider`

I did some more research and got told by a colleague that instead of signing our apk every time we make a slight change, we could extract the apk of App B and sign it with our key only once.

It led me to then create a keystore and key for my team, which I used to re-sign App B's apk and reinstall it on our test device. I then set my Android Studio to automatically sign the debug versions of App A with that exact same key.
The problem is that didn't change anything unfortunately... 
It always ends up with the following exception being thrown:

`Failed to find provider info for com.App.B.provider`

(basically the same error thrown when we are using the default App B apk withouth sending our App A apk to the signing server)

Just to point out, if you're wondering, sending App A's apk to the signing server and running that *does* work and we're getting the data from the `ContentProvider`

So yea, I'm not sure what to do anymore... Any ideas ? 
Also, since I'm not sure I have a clue of what I'm doing, any explanation of how these things are supposed to go would be very welcome !

Answer (score 0):

`<provider>` tag should be placed inside `<application>` tag.
Also, be careful not to put it inside an `<activity>` tag.
Also you can get it working  specify full path in `<authorities>` tag in manifest file (see SearchableDictionary sample code in SDK).

```
<provider android:name=".DictionaryProvider"
   android:authorities="com.example.android.searchabledict.DictionaryProvider">
```

Alternatively you can use external storage,create directories and access the data from there directly.

Comment: I'm not sure how to refer to that tag in the Java code then. At the moment, I use this code to query the `ContentProvider`: `private final Uri APP_B_URI =
            Uri.parse("content://com.App.B/CALENDAR");`

Comment: I was refering the `menifest.xml` file.

Comment: That I got, what I meant was that how can I get a URI out of that tag then ? Since I'm querying the `ContentProvider` at runtime like this: `Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(APP_B_URI, null, where, null, "localstart");`